# NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription ignored

Tags: swift3, cllocationmanager, xcode8

Xcode 8.2 beta 8C30a, Swift 3, iPhone 5s.

I'm writing a weather app that wants to use the iPhone's location.  To get authorisation I have set (all of) the following my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your current location is used to provide you with a local weather forecast.</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your current location is used to provide you with a local weather forecast.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your current location is used to provide you with a local weather forecast.</string>
```

Nevertheless, when I call LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() then I get the following error:

```
This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.
The app's Info.plist must contain an NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key
with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data
```

The key is there but not being seen.  There is no entry for the app in the phone's settings menu (nor under privacy).  Doubtless, I'm missing something simple.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same problem with one particular App, and I have several Apps with the same structure which are working just fine when I request authorization for Location Services.

In all cases, I have localized the Application, so I have several Info.plist files in my XCode project (e.g. one for the Base language which is English, another for French, etc).

I always manually edit my Info.plist files (viewing them "as Source Code") and add the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription fields).

But in this specific App's case, I noticed that XCode was NOT showing the NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription field when I selected the App Target in the Project's list of Targets and then clicked on the "Info" tab. This is odd, because when I check the "Info" tab in my other XCode projects, edits made to the Info.plist file for the Base language appear here. So I manually added a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription field to this "Info" UI and suddenly my new App was working correctly, requesting the user's permission to access Location Services when in use.

I'd recommend checking that all the fields you have added to your Info.plist file are reflected in the Target/Info screen. If they are not, you may have a similar problem, in which case the same fix may work for you.

I am guessing the root cause of the problem is a bug in the localization process. I recall that after selecting the Info.plist file as one of my localized files, I got an error from XCode at build time, complaining that it was missing an Info.plist file (it had moved Info.plist from the base.lproj folder to en.lproj when it "localized" the file). I reinstated the file that XCode had moved from the base.lproj folder to the en.lproj folder, and that seemed to make XCode happy again. But I think somehow it lost the ability to refresh itself, so subsequent additions to the Info.plist file(s) aren't being applied everywhere they need to be).